# Need help changing Max_Execution_Time in phpMyAdmin, I get #1227 - Access denied

Tags: mysql, max-execution-timeout

phpMyAdmin will not allow me to change the Max_Execution_Time from 0 to 600. Whenever I try I receive the message "#1227 - Access denied; You need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEoGm.jpg)

- I am using web based hosting, not local
- Via EasyWP
  **- How can I grant myself the SUPER Privilage?**

I tried editing this myself under "Variables" but could not.

Comment: Login to phpMyAdmin using the `root` database user.

Comment: If you are using a shared mysql database, then it is unlikely that you will ever be allowed to to change any global settings as you can bring the entire database down. Try setting it on session level instead. However, you may not be allowed to that either.

Comment: This is really not a programming question, you need to contact your hosting provider if you need to change a setting and you are not allowed to do so.